# TCL: Return to a higher level?

Tags: tcl

How can I return from a proc to a higher context?
For example: If proc X called another proc Y which called a third proc Z - is there a way to return from Z directly back to X ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From 8.5 onwards, yes. The [`return`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/return.htm) command has a `-level` option which is used to do just that:

```
return -level 2 $someValue
```

Thus, for example:

```
proc X {} {
    puts "X - in"
    Y
    puts "X - out"
}
proc Y {} {
    puts "Y - in"
    Z
    puts "Y - out"
}
proc Z {} {
    puts "Z - in"
    return -level 2 "some value"
    puts "Z - out"
}
X
```

produces this output:

```
X - in
Y - in
Z - in
X - out
```

Note that doing this reduces the reusability of `Z`, but that's your business.

Comment: I've always used `uplevel 1 [list return $some_value]` to do this which works even on older versions of tcl.

Comment: @slebetman: Did you ever check that in a simple harness like the one above? Because when I do, it also prints out “`Y - out`”, indicating that it isn't doing what you're hoping it does…

Answer (score 0):

if You are call "x process"  from "z proc"  then
loop will create in the  your process flow..

Comment: I actually I meant to return to the place where Y was called in X, to continue the program from there. (Y will not be called over and over again)

Comment: i think below answer is suitable for u

Comment: @heyram: you might want to consider rewriting your answer to use proper words. Using phrases like "u r" for "you are" lower the credibility of your answer by a few orders of magnitude.